# Android pass arguments from dialog to calling activity

Tags: java, android, interface

I'm having problems getting data from my dialog to the calling activity.  Been following the android documents, but haven't had luck.  I just want to capture a string that someone enters in an edit text box of my dialog.  Here is my setup.

```
public class CrossoverMainActivity extends Activity implements CrossoverSaveDialog.NoticeDialogListener {

final CrossoverSaveDialog dialog_save = new CrossoverSaveDialog();


    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_save) {

            dialog_save.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog_save");
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            CrossoverDeleteDialog dialog_delete = new CrossoverDeleteDialog();
            //Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            dialog_delete.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog_delete");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then, in another .java file, I have my dialog:

```
public class CrossoverSaveDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface NoticeDialogListener {
        void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    NoticeDialogListener mListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogSave = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crossover_save_dialog, null);

        builder.setView(dialogSave);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(CrossoverSaveDialog.this);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(CrossoverSaveDialog.this);
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my two questions:

- The problem I'm getting is that the compiler is complaining that I'm not implementing the methods of my interface... which I seem to be.  Is there something I'm missing here?
- I have to do this for a second dialog which is different than the one I've shown here.  But, I'll be doing it in the same fashion.  Do I just look in the dialog of the callback method to determine which dialog is being used?  That way I can handle my logic for each dialog.  Or, should I have each dialog with a seperate interface that uses it's each unique methods, and just implement each of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the answer here.

@blender: Maybe I'm mis-understanding this, but I don't think I need to do that right?  I mean, I'm implementing the interface already in my activity class, and I'm getting attached to that via the onAttach within my dialog class aren't I?

Anyhow, here was the blunder.  I was importing the          android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.  Then, in my main activity, I was importing the android.app.DialogFragment.  That was causing my two method callbacks in my main activity to not actually get registered by the compiler it seemed.  I used Android Studio so when you auto import stuff, it can be easy to dismiss the fact that you didn't import the correct namespace.  Doh!

Secondly, I found out that you can just call the dialog.getTag() in the onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog).  You can check that against whichever dialog it is you show.  In this way, you can have multiple dialogs using the same interface methods, and just incorporate your "checking" logic there.

ie, I have this line:

```
dialog_save.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog_save");
```

So I can simply do this to check which dialog I clicked the positive button from:

```html
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // User touched the dialog's positive button
    
    if (dialog.getTag().equals("Dialog_save"){
        //..do stuff...
    }

    if (dialog.getTag().equals("Dialog_cancel"){
        //..do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set your activity to be the Listener for your newly member "mListener"

So in Dialogclass you should create a getter/setter for your listener like this:

```
public NoticeDialogListener getListener() { return mListener; }
public void setListener (NoticeDialogListener listener) { mListener=listener; }
```

and in your activity you would do

```
CrossoverDeleteDialog dialog_delete = new CrossoverDeleteDialog();
        dialog_delete.setListener(this);
        dialog_delete.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog_delete");
```